# Copying files from emulator drive to sd card

Tags: android, copy, user-data, android-sdcard

I see how to mount an SD card in the emulator, but I'm not sure how you move files back and forth between the userdata image and the SD card image. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The first thought that comes to my mind is to first transfer the data from the userdata image file to local filesystem and then transfer back from local to sdcard image.

```
adb pull /data/data/com.example.sample ./sample/
adb push ./sample/ /sdcard/sample/
```

hope I interpreted your question correctly.

Comment: That's a good idea for transfer, but I'd really like to mound the image as a native drive on my OSX system, just as I can the SDCard image with Disk Utility.